# Mobile Dropdown Submenu Opening Link on Click

Tags: mobile, menu, dropdown

Good Day. I created a dropdown menu for my site with multiple dropdowns. On a browser screen everything is working perfectly but on mobile the problem starts. The problem I have is that on my mobile I can click the accommodation link and the dropdown will open, but when I click one of the Beauty dropdowns it selects the nails link and takes me to that page instead of opening the beauty dropdown.

If I click the beauty on the side of the menu it will open correctly but not if I click in the middle of the menu.

Below is my code.

CSS for mobile:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
.navbar-search .search-query:click{
width: 70px;
}
}
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */ 
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
.PL0 {
padding-left: 20px;
}
.PT20 { padding-top:20px;}
.navbar .brand {
padding-bottom: 18px;
}
/* link background */
.nav-collapse .nav>li>a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
}
/* active link */
.nav-collapse .nav>li>a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
}
.nav.social-icons{
text-align: center;
}

.nav.social-icons li{
float: none;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav-collapse .navbar-form, .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
border: 0;
}

/* search form */
.navbar-search {
text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-search .search-query{
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
  }

.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse {
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
  }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 

.navbar .brand {
padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.PL0 {
padding-left: 20px;
}
.PT20 { padding-top:20px;}

/* link background */
.nav-collapse .nav>li>a:focus, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:focus {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

  /* active link */
.nav-collapse .nav>li>a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
  }

  .nav.social-icons{
text-align: center;
  }

  .nav.social-icons li{
float: none;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .nav-collapse .navbar-form, .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
border: 0;
  }

  /* search form */
  .navbar-search {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-search .search-query{
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 

.nav-collapse:click, .nav-collapse.collapse:click {
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

}
```

Here is the menu code:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle"
data-toggle="dropdown">Business<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" >Accommodation
&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="bead-and-breakfast.php">Bead And Breakfast</a></li>
<li><a href="guest-house.php">Guest House</a></li>
<li><a href="lodges.php">Lodges</a></li> 
<li><a href="tours.php">Tours</a></li>
</ul>
</li><hr>
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Beauty
&nbsp;&raquo;    </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="beauty-clinic.php">Beauty Clinic</a></li>
<li><a href="beauty-products.php">Beauty Products</a></li>
<li><a href="hair-salon.php">Hair Salon</a></li>
<li><a href="nails.php">Nails</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Beauty</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Beauty &nbsp;&raquo;
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="beauty-clinic.php">Beauty Clinic</a></li>
<li><a href="beauty-products.php">Beauty Products</a></li>
<li><a href="hair-salon.php">Hair Salon</a></li>
<li ><a href="nails.php">Nails</a></li>
</ul>
</li><hr>
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Beauty &nbsp;&raquo;
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="beauty-clinic.php">Beauty Clinic</a></li>
<li><a href="beauty-products.php">Beauty Products</a></li>
<li><a href="hair-salon.php">Hair Salon</a></li>
<li ><a href="nails.php">Nails</a></li>
</ul>
</li><hr>
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Beauty &nbsp;&raquo;
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="beauty-clinic.php">Beauty Clinic</a></li>
<li><a href="beauty-products.php">Beauty Products</a></li>
<li><a href="hair-salon.php">Hair Salon</a></li>
<li ><a href="nails.php">Nails</a></li>
</ul>
</li><hr>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Hope some one can help me.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], so that we can look at this “live”. // Without a live example, I would guess(!) that you probably have elements overlapping, so you are not actually clicking/tapping the element you think you are …

Comment: Here is a link to my testing page. http://www.mootenverkoop.co.za/menu-test.php

Comment: This doesn’t seem to happen when “Beauty” is clicked first (btw., why does that show up multiple times?), but only if “Accommodation” was opened first. So perhaps a problem in your underlying JavaScript logic …?

Comment: I am currently just testing, that is why it is shown more than once. There is currently no javascript used on the page, it is pure css.

Comment: So this relies purely on `:hover` states? Not sure if that is a good idea on mobile. (And not sure what `:click` is supposed to be, either - is that an actual new CSS state that I missed somehow?)

Comment: I found that :click or :focus works on mobile, my problem is still that the last link in beauty is clicked when another dropdown should open.

Comment: Sorry, I just don’t think this is the proper way to build such a menu if you want it to work on mobile. Some mobile browsers do not support :hover at all, others have the first tap on an element make it go into that state … this is just not reliable. Either use JavaScript to make this work, or go look for another approach (f.e. checkboxes and :checked have better support on mobile.)

Comment: Do you perhaps have a javascript solution that I can use?